# Simple Json format when requesting google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, google-sheets-api

I am using the google spreadsheet api to read from a google sheet in javascript. I need to read a google sheet

And I would like the result to be like this:

```
result = [ {
        Title : 'Item1',
        Description : 'The items in this list are read dynamically from an external file for now. We can specify the Title, the description and the url of icon image.',
        Icon : 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dapino/medical/128/medical-suitecase-icon.png'
    },
    {
        Title : 'Item2',
        Description : 'Some Long description to check how the text will appear if it is too long in the info list view. It should wrap automatically and the height of the row should be adjusted as needed. I will add some more worlds.',
        Icon : 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dapino/summer-holiday/128/compass-icon.png'
    },
    {
        Title : 'Item3',
        Description : 'The pc icon is just a test icon. It can be replaced by any image local or on the server. I just used this one for testing.',
        Icon : 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gabriel-leblanc/historic-mac/128/ibook-g4-12-icon.png'
    },
    {
        Title : 'Item4',
        Description : 'Adding a final item that will be out of range of the view. You will have to scroll to see it. (at least on the iphone)',
        Icon : 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/double-j-design/ravenna-3d/128/V-Card-icon.png'
    }
];
```

When I request the sheet as a json using this  URL as jsonp:

I get a very messy Json . Is there a way I can modify the url to return something similar to what I want? Or something simpler. I am finding it hard to extract the values from the returned Json

Comment: Please thanks the people who answered you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tabletop.js](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop) and the more advanced [Sheetsee.js](http://jlord.github.io/sheetsee.js/) does that job efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to change the returned json to the format you want... If you want a way of doing it without code, I am sorry, but the json looks the same as GData API output. So your options look very limited. Working with the above json or HTML look to be the best options.